# Python create new column with multiplier based on another columns value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm new to python and I'm trying to derive an additional column for an existing dataframe. This column's value would be based on another columns value times a multiplier, here're some examples:
I have this dataframe that indicates workout time for each country. I want to generate an additional column called expected workout time which is going to have a multiplying factor based on the time column. Something like for US expected time = time * 2, for UK expected time = time * 1.5, and for DE expected time = time * 1.

Ideally, I wish I can have a self-defined function for this problem so it will be more flexible to adjust the multiply factor or the way of calculation (right now is multiply but might become add/subtract/modulo in the future)

Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

df = pd.DataFrame()
countries= ['US','DE','UK']
df['country'] = random.choices(countries,k=100)
df['time'] = random.choices(range(20,100),k=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic Pandas solution is to work in two steps:

1. Create an array or series containing the "multiplier" associated with each row. Let's call it `multiplier`.
2. Multiply the multipliers by the values you want to multiply, i.e. `df['expected_workout_time'] = df['time'] * multiplier`.

Step 1 can be accomplished in *several* ways, but I prefer the pure Pandas solution:

```py
# Step 1
country_multipliers = {'US': 2, 'UK': 1.5, 'DE': 1}
multiplier = df['country'].map(country_multipliers)

# Step 2
df['expected_workout_time'] = df['time'] * multiplier
```

The Pandas [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) method is the under-appreciated cousin of [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), but I personally think `Series.map` is more generally useful, and should be the default choice instead of `Series.apply`. In particular, it accepts a "mapping" (a `dict`) instead of a function, in which case the result is the outcome of looking up values in that mapping.

---

If you need extra control over the mapping/lookup/replacement process, you can use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) instead, but I prefer `Series.map` unless I know I need the specific `Series.replace` features.

---

Another option, if you have a really big dataset, is to avoid constructing the intermediate `multiplier` array, and use plain Python list operations to construct the desired data:

```py
country_multipliers = {'US': 2, 'UK': 1.5, 'DE': 1}

def apply_multiplier(country, time):
    return country_multipliers[country] * time

df['expected_workout_time'] = pd.Series(
    map(apply_multiplier, df['country'].array, df['time'].array),
    index=df.index,
)
```

---

Finally, you can use [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for this as well. This can be slow, but it is parallelizable, either using the [Pandarallel library](https://pypi.org/project/pandarallel/) or by manually chunking:

```py
country_multipliers = {'US': 2, 'UK': 1.5, 'DE': 1}

def apply_multiplier(row):
    country, time = row
    return country_multipliers[country] * time

df['expected_workout_time'] = df[['country', 'time']].apply(apply_multiplier, axis=1, raw=True)
```

The `raw=True` option should provide a nice performance improvement. Consult the docs for more information on what it does.